# Abrir link criado via jquery em janela modal?

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend, jquery-ui

O meu problema é o seguinte quando o usuário clica no link add este abre uma janela modal clicando em salvar envia os dados pro server-side via ajax se der tudo certo criar uma nova row na tabela na pagina index com os novos dados contendo dois links um para ediçao e outro para deleção, ambos destes deveriam abrir uma janela pop-up porem  quando clico nesses link no novo registro nao funciona, só funciona se a pagina for recarregada. Alguem poderia me ajudar?

**js:**

```
 $("#btnsubmit").on('click',function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     var title = $("input[name=title]").val();
     var artist = $("input[name=artist]").val();
     var action = 'add';
     $.post("album/ajax",{
          action : action,
          title  : title,
          artist : artist
        },
        function(data){
          if(data.response == true){
              alert("Inserido com sucesso!");
              var row_data= "";
              row_data +="<tr><td>"+title+"</td><td>"+artist+"</td><td><a href='album/edit/"+data.id+"' class='showModal'>Edit</a> <a href='album/delete/"+data.id+"' class='showModal'>Delete</a></td></tr>";
              $("#table").append(row_data);
           } else {
               alert("Nao foi possivel Add!");
           }
        },'json');
   });
```

codigo js para abrir a janela modal

```
 $(function (){
  function handler() {
   if (this.readyState == this.DONE) {
    if (this.status == 200 && this.responseText != null) {
        $("#modal").html(this.responseText);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Something went wrong! Status = ' + this.status);
   }
 }

 var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
 client.onreadystatechange = handler;

 $(document).ready(function () {
 $("a.showModal").click(function () {
    //$("#modal").html('Loading ' + $(this).attr("href"));
    client.open("GET", $(this).attr("href"),true);
    client.send();
 var dialog;
 dialog =   $("#modal").dialog({
        autoOpen:true,
        width: 400,
        height: 450,
        modal: true,
        /*close: function () {
            $("#modal").html('');
        }*/
        buttons: [{ 
           text: "Cancelar", 
           click: function() { 
             dialog.dialog("close"); 
           }
        }],
        close: function () {
            $("#modal").html('');
        }
    });
    return false;
   });
  });
 });
```

**index (main page):**

```
 <?php 
  $title = 'My albums';
  $this->headTitle($title);
?>
 <h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h1>
 <a href="<?php echo $this->url('album', array( 
    'action'=>'add'));?>" class="showModal">Add Modal</a>
 <table class="table" id="table">
 <tr>
     <th>Title</th>
     <th>Artist</th>
     <th>&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach($albums as $album) : ?>
<tr>
 <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($album->title);?></td>
 <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($album->artist);?></td>
<td>
   <a href="<?php echo $this->url('album', array( 
    'action'=>'edit', 'id' => $album->id));?>" class="showModal">Edit Modal</a>
   <a href="<?php echo $this->url('album', array( 
    'action'=>'delete', 'id' => $album->id));?>" class="showModal">Delete Modal</a>
</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
<div id="teste">+</div>
<p id="p"></p>
<div id="modal"></div>
```

Comment: Pode colocar o código que abre o modal? acho que precisa delegar, tipo $(document).on('click', '.showModal', function(){

Comment: Aqui `$("a.showModal").click(function () {` já tentou algo como `$("a.showModal").on('click', function () {` ou até algo como `$(document).on('click', '.showModal', function (event) {`?

Comment: Marcelo Diniz muito obrigado funcionou da ultima maneira que me passou! (y)
assim funciona tbm
    $('body').on('click','a.showModal', function () {

Comment: @PauloSaldanhadasilva o seu problema é de delegação. Marquei como duplicada pois a outra pergunta tem uma resposta boa que explica o problema.